# Javascript Recursive function. Wrong results while storing data in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, recursion

While trying to get all permutations using Heap's algorithm, I met trouble storing the results in array.

The result generated is (from console.log(arr);) 
["1", "2", "3"]
["2", "1", "3"]
["3", "1", "2"]
["1", "3", "2"]
["2", "3", "1"]
["3", "2", "1"]

but only the last value is stored in the arr, and the array stored somehow is this (from console.log(JSON.stringify(allPermutations)); )
["3", "2", "1"]
["3", "2", "1"]
["3", "2", "1"]
["3", "2", "1"]
["3", "2", "1"]
["3", "2", "1"]

```
var allPermutations = [];

function swap(arr,index1,index2){
    var dummy = arr[index1];
    arr[index1] = arr[index2];
    arr[index2] = dummy;
    return arr;
}

function generate(n,arr){
    if(n==1){
        console.log(arr);
            //result:
            //["1", "2", "3"]
            //["2", "1", "3"]
            //["3", "1", "2"]
            //["1", "3", "2"]
            //["2", "3", "1"]
            //["3", "2", "1"]
        allPermutations.push(arr);
    }else{
        for(var i=0;i<n-1;i++){
            generate(n-1,arr);
            if( n%2 ==0){
                arr = swap(arr,i,n-1);
            }else{
                arr = swap(arr,0,n-1);
            }
        }
        generate(n - 1, arr);
    }
}

generate(3,['1','2','3']);

console.log(JSON.stringify(allPermutations));
/*result:
["3","2","1"]
["3","2","1"]
["3","2","1"]
["3","2","1"]
["3","2","1"]
["3","2","1"]*/
```

What's wrong with this? Would love to understand. Thanks

Comment: You keep passing the same array to the next function call, so it changes, and arrays are passed by "reference" *(not really, but close enough)* so the pushed array keeps changing as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `allPermutations.push(arr)` with `allPermutations.push(arr.slice())`.

The problem is, you keep pushing the same array, then changing that array. When you push an array, you don't push a copy of it: you push a reference. There is only one array, and six references to it; when you read them out, they all read the same, because they *are all the same array*.

`.slice()` will give you a new array with the same elements; this way, you get six new arrays into your result, instead of six mentions of the same array.

From one of my earlier answers that is almost-but-not-quite a duplicate, a metaphor I like for this:

> As a metaphor, imagine a theatre director in casting. He turns to an actor, says "You... you'll be Romeo.". Then he looks at the *same* actor, says "You... you'll be Mercutio. Here, Mercutio, take this sword. Romeo... who told you to get a sword?!?" completely failing to realise that, if Romeo and Mercutio are the *same person*, if one of them picks up a sword, the other does it too.

Comment: wow. That's it! Thanks for your awesome explanation. will accept your answer once the time limit has passed.

Answer (score 0):

That's because arrays are objects, and objects are passed by value, but that value is a reference.

Then, your code keeps pushing the same `arr` reference to `allPermutations`. But the values in that reference are modified later.

Instead, you should push a copy of the array. You can copy it with `.slice()`.

```js
var allPermutations = [];
function swap(arr, index1, index2) {
  var dummy = arr[index1];
  arr[index1] = arr[index2];
  arr[index2] = dummy;
  return arr;
}
function generate(n, arr) {
  if (n == 1) {
    allPermutations.push(arr.slice());
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
      generate(n - 1, arr);
      if (n % 2 == 0) {
        arr = swap(arr, i, n - 1);
      } else {
        arr = swap(arr, 0, n - 1);
      }
    }
    generate(n - 1, arr);
  }
}
generate(3, ['1', '2', '3']);
document.write(JSON.stringify(allPermutations));
```